# How to set PCI registers

Tags: windows-10, pci-express, register

What program can I use to set PCI configuration registers from Windows 10?
I have tried using setpci and BAR-edit, but when I try to write to the registers, it has no effect; when I try to read back the register after writing, it hasn't changed.

I don't think they are readonly because setpci is used in linux to set registers from userspace.

Comment: Yes, both instances for BAR-edit, I ran as Admin and the cmd window I used to run setpci was also run as Admin :)

Comment: Have you already seen this tool here: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/10316/Configuration-Utility-PCIECCONFIG10-EXE- stating to do what you need? It seems to install fine on Windows 10 just not sure how to use it to test further but one other quick thought I wanted to run by you.

Comment: Additionally, see if you can power cycle a PCI device with the tool you use after making the changes and see if that makes them become effective. Let me know how it goes or if any of that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks, the Intel tool doesn't work on Windows 10, it says "Driver Error, Only one instance of the application can be running". Of course, there is no other instance of the application in task manager :)
But that is the exact type of tool I'm looking for, just for Win 10